# How to maintain shredded abs while bulking up?

Tags: weightlifting, abdominals, eating-habits

Before I started lifting and eating more calories than I burn I had shredded six pack abs... Probably because I play baseball and did push ups and sit ups... But now I am lifting and eating and they seem to be slowly going away... How do I bulk and keep my ab muscles visible at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

**How to maintain shredded abs while bulking up?**

By lean bulking aka small caloric surplus([**TDEE**](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/) + 100~500 calories).

However, if you are afraid of not being able to see your abs, consider doing **small cuts for 1-2 weeks**(not recommended since you are lean bulking and you should not be gaining too much fat while doing so).